# is there map for ipv4 internet?

Tags: web, networking, port-scanning

sorry my poor title but I don't know how to express my intention.

In ipv4 there are 2**32 addresses right?

and then if I send 1024 packets per second I could check all the devices of the internet in 1165 hours to create map of the internet. with it I want to make a topology of the internet

it's not that bad, if I go with multiple computers like raspberry pie it would be more faster.

if it's not me but somewhat organization or people and they have enough time, it could even scanning all the ports of all the devices of the internet..!

is my thought a daydream? or somebody already did it? please let me know! I'm curious

Comment: How would you map anycast addresses, like `8.8.8.8` that exist simultaneously in many parts of the world, and you would get a different location from different test places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in the actual physical location of an IP address, then there are many sources compiled already available, like the one [here](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite2-free-geolocation-data) for free. Some are more accurate(commercial ones) than others.

If you just want to know if an IP address is alive or what services are available then you are out of luck as many of these "public" IP addresses are only accessible from whitelisted sources and/or heavily protected from folks like you trying to sniff around for profiling reasons.

If you would like to map out the topology of the Internet, you could get a view of the Autonomous Systems (collection of IP network addresses typically owned by ISPs or larger corporations) by looking at publicly accessible BGP looking glasses. BGP is the protocol that controls the routing of packets on the Internet. Please note that this is very dynamic and changes frequently due to the dynamic nature of path selection algorythms.